# How to set a custom date format when deserializing from a stream using Json.Net

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I want to parse a `DateTime` from a JSON stream.

The pattern for the Date is `YYYY/MM/DD`.

How can I set this custom format on the settings of the Serializer or using the DateParseHandling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the `DateFormatString` on the `JsonSerializer` to the format you need.  Json.Net uses the same [format specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) as the .NET framework.

Here is an example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"{ ""date"" : ""2014/10/07"" }";

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms))
        using (JsonTextReader jtr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
            ser.DateFormatString = "yyyy/MM/dd";
            Foo foo = ser.Deserialize<Foo>(jtr);
            Console.WriteLine(foo.Date.ToLongDateString());
        }
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Example output:

```
Tuesday, October 07, 2014
```

Comment: Nitpick: in C# strings are UTF16 and not UTF8

Comment: @ChrisWue True, C# strings use UTF-16 internally; however, StreamReader expects UTF-8 by default ([doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfzs7at(v=vs.110).aspx)), which is why I chose to use UTF-8 encoding here.  I suppose I could have gotten the bytes as UTF-16 and then passed the UTF-16 Encoding to the constructor of the StreamReader, but that just makes the example code more complicated for not much benefit.  The OP is probably getting his JSON from some other kind of Stream that has UTF-8 encoded characters, in which case constructing a StreamReader with UTF-16 would be incorrect.